# How to fill geom_point with border only one color?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the mpg dataset in R. Trying to do a scatterplot graph with points filled based on 'drv' category with a white border. First image shown below is what I want (taken from https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html section 3.6). But the graph I get is just one color (2nd picture). Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, fill = drv, color = "white", stroke = 3))
```

[image: What I want]

[image: What I'm getting]

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = mpg) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, fill = drv), color = "white", stroke = 3, shape = 21)`. Default points have no fill. Therefore use `shape=21` = points with fill. Additionally if you want to set a color, stroke or shape do so outside of aes().

Answer (score 2):

As @stefan mentioned in the comments the default `shape` for `geom_point()` is solid and only has a `color` aesthetic but not a `fill` or `stroke` attribute. To use those you need to change the `shape` to something else such as `21`. See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_shape.html) for more details on some of the available shapes... there are MANY.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = mpg) +
  geom_point(
    mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, fill = drv),
    color = "white",
    stroke = 3,
    shape = 21,
    size = 4
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>